# How to make a cross compiler using gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, fedora, cross-compiling

Though there are many tutorials online on how to make a cross compiler, I am actually not getting it.

I am using `fedora 16` and already have `gcc` installed. I am not sure about `binutils`. How do I make a cross compiler for *my own OS* ***(the target)***? I was reading [here on os dev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) but I don't get it. I mean, what do I do ? I just don't follow there steps.

**Note :** *I want to build a cross compiler for the same architecture I am currently working on.I mean the same architecture that is running fedora.*

Comment: This is a good guide for building the utilities (binutils, newlib) and gcc. http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2005-08/msg00114/l-cross-ltr.pdf

Comment: That will depend on what your _own OS_ looks like. If it is a homegrown OS for the same architecture as your Fedora, then it is the easiest situation: you may solve with a custom linker script.

Comment: Is using gcc compulsory for you? If not, then you can try llvm-clang. It is much easier to learn llvm-clang because it is designed to be that way. Look for 'Tutorial: Building backend in 24 hours - A step by step tutorial to build a backend.' in http://llvm.org/devmtg/2009-10/

Answer (score 1):

If the architecture of *your own OS* is the same than your running OS, then you do not need a new compiler, the same you already have will do. You may still need custom `binutils`, though, but that depends on the format of the executables *your own OS* needs.

What I've done for *my own toy OS* is to make it understand ELF binaries: it is an absurdly easy format to load and run. And this way you can use the standard `binutils` of your OS. You just have to link your executables with a custom linker script, and not to link with any linux library.

But note that many people [consider this not such a good idea](http://wiki.osdev.org/Why_do_I_need_a_Cross_Compiler?), but it may keep you going for a while.

My compiler command looks like:

```
%.o: %.c
        gcc -c -o $@ -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -Os -g -Wall $<
```

And my linker command:

```
%.myexe: %.o
        ld -o $@ -T myexe.ld $^ `gcc -print-libgcc-file-name`
```

For reference, the linker script is `myexe.ld`:

```
ENTRY(main)

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }
    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of the `.` and `*` you used in the linker script. Is this some kind of language ? I know nothing about it

Comment: @SuhailGupta: You can read the `info ld` for details. Basically, the `SECTIONS` section is used to define the layout of the final executable. For example, the final ELF section named `.text` (`.text : { ... }`) will be composed of the concatenations of the `.text` sections (`(.text)`) from every object file (`*`). There is a more to it, of course, this is just the very basics. The extra bits depend a lot on the features of your OS.