# How do you use gcc to generate assembly code in MIPS syntax?

Tags: gcc, mips, dev-c++, gcc-warning, mips32

Dev-C++ uses AT&T assembly, and I want to convert that in MIPS. I can't find the command for the Windows 10 (64bit) that does that. Linux for example uses **mips-linux-gnu-g++ -march=mips32r2 -S dll.c**, I think. The file I want to convert is **.cpp**, if that helps.

Comment: I think you are looking for a cross compiler (you compile under Windows on x86 for some other OS on MIPS). You can build one your own (takes some time and is, unless something changed in the past 10 years, a steep learning experience for a novice) or use something pre-built. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45035521/3150802) brought up the [Codescape MIPS SDK](https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/) (with I have just heard about for the first time).

Comment: the process to convert from the source code file to executable binary is called "compilation" and if the binary is in another architecture it's called cross compile. [How to cross-compile for MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5291190/995714), [How to make a cross compiler using gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17675029/995714)